# tabs permission or content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension that needs to show a page action on amazon.com pages.

Would it be better to request the "tabs" permission or to inject a content script into amazon.com pages?

The tabs permission strikes me as using less resources (because it just checks the URL against a regex in the background script) but I think it's a scarier permission message ("access your tabs and browsing activity")?

Injecting a content script into amazon.com pages seems like it would take more resources it but would only need permission to amazon.com...

Answer (score 0):

It is a generic question and answer depends on Client to Client. You have pointed out the + and - of each.

I suggest you to go for content scripts if your clients are particular about security and privacy, in this you are adding an extra load to pages(with `content scripts` and `message passing`) which may slow down the normal execution process.

I suggest you to go for tab permission, if you are all about performance. It is a native API, and executes in background page no extra load on tabs. Many extensions on web store does use tabs API, i dont think this would scare them as this is not new.

However, it is all about your target section of users.